# jboss error migrating EJB 2.X ap to jboss 5

Tags: jboss5.x, ejb-2.x

I migrating someone else's EJB 2.X app from jboss 3 to jboss 5 (and then maybe onto AS7).
When I do a test deployment of one of the EJBs I am getting this error

```
org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: Could not load class: 
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.cmp.jdbc.metadata.JDBCEntityCommandMetaData.<init>   
(JDBCEntityCommandMetaData.java:76)
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.cmp.jdbc.metadata.JDBCEntityMetaData.<init>
(JDBCEntityMetaData.java:954)...
```

Googling this stack trace doesn't give me any leads I can work on. As far as I can tell this means that the entity-command in conf/standardjbosscmp-jdbc.xml is wrong but I have no idea what it should be. Looking at the jboss 3 conf/standardjbosscmp-jdbc.xml file doesn't even have an entity-command listed so I assume "default" should be ok, no? I am using Oracle 11g, if that is meaningful and otherwise seem to have no db connection issues. The Oracle datasource seems to be created without problems. This is the very first error in the output. Any clues as to what i should look a to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you build everything against JBoss 5 libs?  This could be a build problem...

Comment: For the one basic EJB I am testing deployment with he only Jboss 5 specific lib that I need is jboss-javaee.jar and I am using that. I have placed jboss-javaee.jar in the lib/ directory. Any other ideas? I am not even sure where to poke next to get another clue?

Comment: you should not put that in your war lib (or any other lib), what is the artifact here (war, ear, jar)?